# Capture log output from subprocesses

Tags: python

So let's say I've got a piece of code that looks like this:

main.py

```
def get_stdout():
    sys.stdout = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "w")
    foo.foo()

p = Process(target=get_stdout)
p.start()
```

foo.py

```
def foo():
    my_logger.info('LOG INFO HERE') 

my_logger = logging.getLogger()
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
logHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('LOG: - %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
my_logger.addHandler(logHandler)
```

The logger is defined at the bottom the foo module. When I call `python main.py`, the intention is to spawn a subprocess that calls `foo()` from the foo module and capture its log output and write it to a file. This example doesn't work because the output stream of the logger object is defined when the module is first initialized, so it just gets written to terminal and not to the file.

What's the best way to get around this? Right now, each module has only a single instance of the logger class and I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I'm drawing a blank on being able to use the logging module and still be able to isolate loglines from separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

By default, log messages are written to `sys.stderr`, not `sys.stdout`, so you need to redirect stderr instead:

```
def get_stdout():  # Maybe rename this
    sys.stderr = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "w")
    foo.foo()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've had it as `sys.stderr = sys.stdout = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "w")` to redirect both streams and it still didn't work.